# PHP datepicker control and event calendar needed

Tags: php, calendar

I'm looking for suggestions for a PHP:

1. calendar control/widget that I can embed on a web page to enable users to select dates.  A datepicker.
2. calendar software that will provide weekly calendar view, similar to what Microsoft Outlook provides.  It should display days of the week in columns and rows representing timeslots.  Each cell would display events that occur on a day/timeslot
   [image]
   <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/uk/atwork/images/office2007/outlook2007_todo.jpg))</sub>

I'm not looking for one piece of software that does both.  It doesn't have to be fancy or full featured.  I need something basic for a little project.  It would be great if the software DIDN'T rely on a database or if it does, it can support Oracle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JQuery's datepicker:

homepage: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/

demos: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

As for a comprehensive calendar organizer unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: It looks like there's an official JQuery datepicker: http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I use [DHTML Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/). It works everywhere and is easily skinnable and also comes with some very nice skins (other than the ugly demo on their site).

Regarding the full calendar, have you thought about integrating with [Google Calendar](http://google.com/calendar)? They have already done all of this and of course it's completely browser compatible.

Comment: I'll take a look at Google Calendar and if the programming effort is not cumbersome, I'll probably use it.  Thanks.

Comment: You can easily integrate with Google Calendar using the iCal. A couple links: http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358   http://www.googletutor.com/2007/01/24/syncing-google-calendar-with-ical/

Answer (score 1):

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) provides a pretty flexible month-view, but not a week view. Might be able to extend it though.

Comment: as of 2016-04-15 the FullCalendar project appears to have month, week, and days views.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to make a custom one take a look at the PHP [calendar book](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.calendar.php).

Unfortunately I haven't used any of these myself.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something that was more complete.